# Where can I find my Chrome update log?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I can find the current version in:

```
chrome://version/
chrome://settings/help
C:\Users\<myUser>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Last Version
```

But where can I find the update history of my chrome, so for example what version I had installed three weeks ago?

Do I really need to write a batch on my own? A batch which hourly copies the 'Last Version'-file from

```
C:\Users\<myUser>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\
```

into an own chrome-history folder to have some kind of self-made update log?

Comment: As far as I know the update history is not stored anywhere.

Comment: 3 weeks ago you would have had the previous version if it was the current version since a new version of Chrome is released every 4 weeks

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, i'm afraid so too. unfortunately, i haven't yet found an official source on the internet that confirms this.

Comment: @Ramhound I guess it's not always 4 weeks. If you look at the stable channel here: https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/search/label/Desktop%20Update (as of 15.11.2022): the last release was on 8.11.2022 and the penultimate release was on 27.10.2022.

Comment: @else42.de - I found those blog articles are not posted the day the release is released